# Changing values within javascript for loop

Tags: javascript, html, perl

I have a form that generates tables using two Javascript loops. Here is the code - much simplified. (I have more code between the X and y loops, and for the rest of the perl script which have been omitted)

```
   for (x=0; x<questions.length; x++){


for (y=1; y<questions[x].length; y++){
var code='<tr><td colspan="2" align="center" bgcolor="#dddddd"><hr width="70%"></td></tr>'
+'<tr><td bgcolor="'+tab_col[x][y]+'" valign="top">'
+'<font class="main2"><font color="'+text[x][y]+'">'+questions[x][y]+'</td>'
+'<td bgcolor="#dddddd"><font class="small2"><b>Cell color<br>'
+'<input type="text" onChange="return update(1,'+x+','+y+',this.value);" size="8" maxlength="7" name="cell_cols'+x+'_'+y+'" value="'+tab_col[x][y]+'"><br>'
+'<b>Text color</b><br><input type="text" onChange="return update(2,'+x+','+y+',this.value);" size="8" maxlength="7" name="ans_cols'+x+'_'+y+'" value="'+text[x][y]+'"></td></tr>'
+'<tr><td><hr size="10" color="'+line[x][y]+'" name="line_'+x+'_'+y+'"></td><td  bgcolor="#dddddd"><font class="small2"><b>Bar Graph</b></font><br>'
+'<input type="text" onChange="return update(3,'+x+','+y+',this.value);" size="8" maxlength="7" name="bar_line'+x+'_'+y+'" value="'+line[x][y]+'"></td></td></tr>';
document.write(code);
}

}
```

You can see that towards the bottom, I have given a HR tag a value `name="line_'+x+'_'+y",` and below that a function call to u`pdate(3,'+x+','+y+',this.value)`. (When the user enters a new color -this value- it pops off to the function (not shown))

Within the function, my theory is that using either: `document.formname['line_'+x+'_'+y].value=col; or document.getElementById('line_'+x+'_'+y).value=col;`

would change the color of the HR tag ... but in all cases, it tells me the item does not exist (null) ** Have tried it with and without ".value", but makes no difference.

I am presuming this is because it is not a physical part of the HTML code that it cannot be seen. ANy work around?

Bear in mind there could be any number of X questions on a page, and each can have a variable number of Y answers. And once I've cracked this one, I need to set "Cell Color" and "Text Color"

** In case you're wondering, it's a survey script which will display questions and options in user defined colours, and show the bar graph results in user definded colours. At present, I am asking users to enter the colours on a form, and then click a preview button. But -trying to be clever- I'm now trying to amend the script so updates the screen colours on the fly.

The format of function update is (1-2or 3,x,y,col) where 1=table cell color, 2=text color 3=bar graph colour. X is the question number, and y is the answer number such as 1-5

Answer (score 0):

Try using the 'id' attribute instead of 'name' in your HR. This should make getElementById much happier.

Comment: Doh! Talk about "Can't see the wood for the trees!" Spent about three hours puzzling thus far! (That, and I needed to "style.color=col" So it now reads " +\\' ... bar_line+\\'x+\\'_\\'+y ...\\' " in the code, and in the function document.getElementById(\\'bar_line\\'+x+\\'_\\'+y).style.color=col Simple when you use the right syntax!! (Excuse double lines, but can't see how to add single quotes without turning on italics

Comment: I know how it feels... All too well :)